# angular 6 create multiple instances of a class using injected service

Tags: angular6

I want to generate a class in angular 6 and instantiate it twice. Each will maintain its own state. This is easy enough by creating a class and new'ing up each instance. But I want to use an Angular 6 service in each instance. Angular injection uses the constructor for injection. So what's the best way to generate to do this?

private widgetA = new widget(1);
   private widgetB = new widget(2);

export class widget {
       constructor(
                     private data: any,
                     private dataService: DataService
                  ) {}
   }

Comment: have you found a way to accomplish that?

Comment: I posted what I did below. Good luck, it may not be the best answer but other avenues turned out to be too difficult

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular 6 and followed this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/38309481/angular-2-inject-service-into-class.
When I built my site in production mode I did get warnings saying I may not be able to upgrade without changing this code. So use at your own risk